# Win32: Monitoring for files being created or changed

Tags: c++, winapi, file-io

1) How can I use `FindFirstChangeNotification` / `FindNextChangeNotification` + `ReadDirectoryChanges` to detect certain files being created or removed?

2) Is the `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE` a reliable indicator of a file change?

---

Application: I have an explicit list of files that may be located in different folders. Display contents depends on the first file in the lsit that actually exists. For this, I want to add an auto-refresh mechanism.

Thus I need to detect "more important" files being created, the current file being changed or removed.

The list isn't long (maybe a dozen or so files), so I *could* poll the files, but for some applications the polling interval should be 50..80ms, ad I wonder if the monitoring API's are a better choice.

Response times should not exceed 200ms (not including any stalls due to unresponsive disks or high system load), but under ideal conditions, update should appear "immediate" to a human operator, without incurring high system load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The monitoring functions are a much better and cleanerr solution than polling, which itself would affect performance. But your response times cannot be guaranteed - Windows is not an RTS.